# for the second update photo not change using android studio and mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

i had some problems when **updating** photo profile in android studio and mysql. but for the process update to database there is no problem and photo updating success. for the first time update photo profile **success changed** in imageview and **photo was upload** to folder "upload" inside xampp, for the second update **it won't** changed **instead** in imageview it using **previous update**. but in folder "upload" inside xampp the **previous photo** is changed with the **new photo** i was uploaded before. i try to refresh activity with onRestart() it failed, i hope you understand for my question. please help me.

> here the php code :

```
    <?php
    include "koneksi.php";

    $gambar = $_POST['foto'];
    $id = $_POST['id_user'];


    class emp{}

    $path = "profil_upload/$id.png";
    $actualpath = "http://192.168.173.1/StudioFoto/$path";

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET foto='".$actualpath."' WHERE id='".$id."'");

        if ($query) {
            file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($gambar));
            $response = new emp();
            $response->success = 1;
            $response->message = "Data berhasil di simpan";
            die(json_encode($response));
        } else{ 
            $response = new emp();
            $response->success = 0;
            $response->message = "Error simpan Data";
            die(json_encode($response)); 
        }   

?>
```

> here method for upload:

```
private void uploadImage() {

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_update_foto, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                // Cek error node pada json
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Insert", jObj.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(UploadFoto.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadFoto.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(UploadFoto.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters ke post url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            //Converting Bitmap to String
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

            //Adding parameters
            params.put("foto", image);
            params.put("id_user", id);
            return params;
        }

    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: thanks @tadman, so the problem is I can use **mysql_query** for my php code, oke I wan to try using PDO, I hope it help my problem.

Comment: `mysql_query` has been removed from PHP so one way or the other you have to stop using it. PDO is a good place to start. Also try to avoid using `die` to send content back to the browser. That's what `echo` is for.